# Rewriting dynamic URLs using URL parameters through htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite this url / query using .htaccess

```
/immobiliensuche/?adv_location=Pforzheim&filter_search_type%5B%5D=wohnung&filter_search_action%5B%5D=mieten&is2=1&submit=Suchen&wpestate_regular_search_nonce=85c48a652f&_wp_http_referer=%2F
```

to

```
/immobiliensuche/pforzheim/wohnung/mieten
```

---> "**pforzheim**", "**wohnung**" and "**mieten**" are variables in search fields.

I tried different variations but they don't seem to work. Does someone has an idea ?

Comment: You might consider adding "url parameters" to your title 
`filter_search_action%5B%5D=mieten` and `filter_search_type%5B%5D=wohnung` are both url parameters so you might have better luck with something like 
`Rewriting dynamic URLs using URL parameters through htaccess`

I would also specify in your question whether you have rewriting working at all currently. Step one would be rewriting your original url to `/test` or something to ensure that the mechanism is working as expected, then you can address using those params in the rewrite

Comment: I've done that, thank you !